# Insert the updated table record in some other table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I have 2 tables:

- A - columns: id, f1, f2, f3
- B - columns: f1, f2, f3, pid

I want to migrate all the values of f1, f2 and f3 from table B to table A. For `id` column of table A, I want to generate it using a sequence generator. I am able to achieve this using the following query:

```
INSERT INTO A (id, f1, f2, f3)
    SELECT 
        mysequence.nextval, f1, f2, f3
    FROM B;
```

Now my requirement is to update the column `pid` in table B which would be same as `id` in table A. I can do this after executing my first query.

But I want to know whether all of this is possible in a single query? Because executing it for 2 times will require iterating over the tables twice. Is it possible in a single query?

Comment: Please specify the technology you are using, like sql-server, mysql, etc.

Comment: I am using Hana DB